# Custom User Profile Component not visible in the Community Builder

Tags: lightning, community, community-builder

I am trying to override the standard user profile component with a custom component,but it is not coming in the builder to choose. I even tried with the code given in the salesforce document still I cannot see the component in the list

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:profileMenuInterface,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global">
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]" default="Option 1, Option 2"/>
<ui:menu >
    <ui:menuTriggerLink aura:id="trigger" label="Profile Menu"/>
    <ui:menuList class="actionMenu" aura:id="actionMenu">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="itemLabel">
            <ui:actionMenuItem label="{!itemLabel}" click="{!c.handleClick}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:menuList>
</ui:menu>
</aura:component>
```

[image: l]

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Hi Ankur!

Did you find a solution to that? I've been battling with this for hours now..

Comment: no didn't got any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Before tackling the main issue, you need to update your component and use only appropriate interfaces. To make your component available for record pages and any other type of page, implement the [`flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes/documentation) interface, likewise, to make your component appear in Experience Builder, it must implement the [`forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes/documentation) interface and remove individual interfaces.

Once the component is saved successfully, it should appear in the community builder component section. Try refreshing or reopening the community builder tab. Sometimes, in community, it is related to caching.

Comment: Hi Mahmood, I don't want that component in my community builder component section but in the user profile component section for that "forceCommunity:profileMenuInterface" is required and I have written that in my code and it is still not working.